# TOpenDialog and Multi Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, firemonkey, freeze, delphi-11-alexandria

This is very curious behaviour of simple Embarcadero Delphi (v. 11.3) application...
When same thread is launched 2 or 3 times (see code below) with 2 or 3 times click on Button1, an TOpenDialog window (click on Button2 AFTER last instance of thread ended) freezes the application. No error message is rised and it is necessary to close app from Win task manager (Ctrl+Alt+Del).

```
{MAIN UNIT}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  MyThread:= TMyThread.Create(false);
End;
    
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  OpenDialog1.Execute;
End;
  
{THREAD UNIT}
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
Begin
  Sleep(2000);
  Synchronize(UpdateMainForm);
End;
    
procedure TMyThread.UpdateMainForm;
Begin
  Form1.Label1.Text:= 'Now thread ended!';
  EndMyThread;
End;

procedure TMyThread.EndMyThread;
Begin
  FreeOnTerminate:= true;
End;
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: FreeOnTerminate is executed in the context of the main (VCL) thread. Other than that, code looks fine.

Comment: @KenWhite the Execute method uses Synchronize, so UpdateMainForm sets the label text in the context of the VCL thread.

Comment: Please include the complete source code for both classes.

Comment: Code you have shown does not cause any freezes. Besides that changing memory management of the thread after it started running is a bad coding practice, that causes more problems than it solves (if any). Since you are assigning constructed thread to `MyThread` variable, I suspect you are using that variable in some other code. If you want to have self destroying thread, you should not take and store a reference o such thread as it will become invalid reference after the thread self destructs.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar code is only that I posted. None call are in other section. My action is simply to press many time (2/3) Button1 and create many instance of thread. Note that non other control in main form causes freeze or some error. Only Button2 press at the execute method of OpenDialog.

Comment: Obviously the code you posted is not complete. Where is `MyThread` declared?  Is your application VCL or FMX based. How do you know when the last thread has stopped running if you only update label with the same text, that will not change after the first thread finishes and other may still be running. On which platform do you experience the problem? There is nothing in the code you posted that would cause a freeze you are describing. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Thank you. Application is FMX based. At soon at possible I post all units. But, except USES declaratiion, all is in my previous post.

Comment: Put your code in a single unit. There is no need to have it all separated. This is a purpose of creating minimal reproducible example. Creating new project with minimal code that shows the problematic behavior.

Comment: Ok. By this evening (Italian time) I will send the code. Thank you very much for yours answers.

Answer (score 1):

FreeOnTerminate := True is executed in the context of the main (VCL) thread in your code.

The line

```
FreeOnTerminate := True;
```

should be in the TMyThread.Create constructor instead.

---

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TThread.FreeOnTerminate

Comment: Thank you a lot.
At soon at possible I will try this!

Comment: Why do you think you can't set `FreeOnTerminate` from the main thread? To me it is absolutely legal.

Comment: @zed one reason is given in the comments: `changing memory management of the thread after it started running is a bad coding practice, that causes more problems than it solves (if any).`

Comment: WIth this solution (FreeOnTerminate := True; in Thread constructor) ALL WORKS!!!
Thank you a lot!!!!!!!